# Which commuter flight was forced to land in a cornfield in '96 or '97?

Tags: commercial-aviation, emergency, accidents, accident-investigation

Last night a friend's wife was describing her experience as a child being on a flight that encountered a flock of Canadian geese, where at least one engine was lost to a bird strike. I suspect both engines may have been lost, or at least compromised, because she said the plane ultimately landed in a cornfield. She said the oxygen masks deployed, and she used the inflatable slide to deplane.

If her memory is correct the flight departed Indianapolis, IN, bound for Trenton, NJ. Based on her age, we thought the flight was probably in 1996 or 1997. She said it was a "small plane", but it was certainly a commercial flight, and I believe a jet (not a turboprop). She described two seats straddling the aisle.

Her memory of the event emphasized surreal, sensory details, so I suspect some uncertainty among the facts useful for finding this flight.

TL;DR here are the useful details:

- Probably 1996 or 1997
- Departed Indianapolis, IN
- (Update 2.20.2018: She confirms it was [Indianapolis International](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indianapolis_International_Airport))
- Intended arrival in Trenton, NJ
- Engine(s) out, presumably due to bird strikes (Canadian geese)
- Emergency landing in a field (possibly a cornfield)
- (Update 2.20.2018: This was a Pennsylvania cornfield)

To my surprise I've been unable to Google more information, so I'm hoping someone here has a better angle on researching this interesting flight.

Comment: Nothing jumps out from https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bird_strike#History_of_Incidents

Comment: Are you sure the aircraft ever became airborne? I.e. did it **land** in a cornfield or could it have been an overrun after an aborted take-off?

Comment: No matching incidents here either: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indianapolis_International_Airport?wprov=sfla1 KIND isn't exactly surrounded by fields, so an incident in close proximity to the field seems unlikely.

Comment: And no matches records on the ASN database (Collisons with birds) https://aviation-safety.net/database/dblist.php?Event=COOB

Comment: Enter search terms on NTSB website https://ntsb.gov/_layouts/ntsb.aviation/index.aspx

Comment: Thanks for the helpful feedback. Some good questions here. If possible I'll try to get some more specific details.

Comment: The only crashes I found that were even remotely close are United Express 5925 (not her flight, all involved were killed) and the propeller failure of the ASA commuter in the Southeast (1995). Nothing that matches the incident and location you describe, though.

Comment: One seat on each side of the aisle would suggest a small turboprop plane like the Beech 1900. Even the small regional jets have a 1-2 layout. And a plane of such size would be low enough to not need to have inflatable slides.

Comment: It is unclear what you mean by two seats straddling the isle. Do you mean a pair of seats on either side of the isle (4 across) or do you mean two seats across? And for everyone else, note that this detail may not be helpful as an upper class cabin arrangement could feature only one seat on either side of the isle (2 across), and this could be the detail remembered.

Comment: It's really tough to hunt down non-fatal accidents without some specific info. The sheer volume of mishaps is hard to wade through. The NTSB site lists 2270 accidents just in 1996

Comment: What about this: CHI971A029.  https://app.ntsb.gov/pdfgenerator/ReportGeneratorFile.ashx?EventID=20001208X07001&AKey=1&RType=Final&IType=IA

Comment: @wbeard52 thanks for staying on the hunt, but I doubt that's it. It might be best to put this question on ice until I can ask her for some more specific details. Honestly, I expected this to result in a quick answer from wiser av researchers like yourself. That it remains a mystery based on the details I was provided has me wondering if the flight as remembered  has radical variations from the actual flight. In other words, I'm now fearing it may have gained theatrical embellishments over the years. In hindsight, I probably wasn't expected to turn around and fact-check it haha :)

Comment: I am skeptical that there was ever scheduled non-stop service between Indianapolis and Trenton; IND, while sizeable, is not huge, and Trenton is a small airport that has [intermittently gained and lost scheduled service over the years.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trenton%E2%80%93Mercer_Airport#Former_commercial_service)  Eastwind Airlines did use it as a hub in the '90s, but as far as I can tell they never flew to Indianapolis.

Comment: Nothing on the Wikipedia lists for aviation incidents/accidents in either years refers to cornfields or anything of the like. There was in incident in the 70s, I believe, in which what looked like a DC3 belonging to the USA army crashed into a cornfield. It killed everyone on board, however. Doesn't sound like your story at all. Sorry pal

Comment: The only commuter aircraft off-field landing in a corn field that I can find that even comes close to the description is this one, an Aspen Airways/United Express Convair 580, but it was in January 1989, and in Colorado.

https://www.ntsb.gov/_layouts/ntsb.aviation/Results.aspx?queryId=0b239aa8-3596-401c-ae5c-e4322035f7aa

I found the story in the Los Angeles Times archive here: http://articles.latimes.com/keyword/commuter-plane

Comment: Aviation-Safety Network lists all major aircraft accidents and incidents. Here is a list sorted by "bird strike": https://aviation-safety.net/database/dblist.php?Event=COOB

Comment: @MarkJonesJr., if you see my comment above I've since assumed the details I was given are a combination of truths, misrememberings, and a few years worth of embellishments. So I'm not sure this question is answerable, as asked. However if you'll write an abstracted answer combining wbeard52's comment about ntsb.gov and your comment mentioning aviation-safety.net, with appropriate search terms and such, I'll give you the accepted answer. In lieu of being, answerable, I think the best answer possible is one that demonstrates how to research a flight like this in the first place. :)

Answer (score 5):

From the Los Angeles Times newspaper, Jan. 21, 1989.

> BUENA VISTA, Colo. — A commuter plane carrying 26 passengers lost power Friday and made an emergency landing in a cornfield, but no one was injured, authorities said. Airline officials had not determined what caused the engines of the United Express plane, a Convair 580 twin-engine propjet, to shut down.

Here is the link: [LA Times](http://articles.latimes.com/1989-01-21/news/mn-872_1_commuter-plane)

Comment: +1 for effort...but this seems not to have been it. I texted her and she says it was "late spring, heading into summer". But she did re-confirm it was a small plane, "couldn't have been more than 30 (people)".